# Calculate angles from connected links and point coordinates

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a problem. Earlier I posted a subproblem of this one but poorly asked so I hope I do better this time.

I have an example which is a more simple one of my actual problem:

I want to find two angles (`theta_2` and `theta_3`) given two links with known link lengths(`a2`, `a3`) and a known end point `(r,s)`.

[image: Problem 1]

With the law of cosines the two angles theta_2 and theta_3 can be found.

`theta_3 = atan2(d, +-sqrt(1-d^2))`
where

`d = (r^2 + s^2 - a2^2 - a3^2) / (2*a2*a3)`

theta_2 then becomes:

`theta_2 = atan2(r,s) - atan2(a2+a3*cos(theta_3), a3*sin(theta_3))`

And that is all understood. But now if I make the problem slightly more complicated I cannot figure out how to find these angles anymore.

Now consider this problem which is exactely the same as problem 1, just with a rigidly attached link at the end point in a 90 degree angle:

[image: Problem 2]

How can I now solve for the angles given only the three link lengths (`a2, a3, d`) and the coordinates of point `D`?

Comment: Please provide a link to the "sub problem" you posted earlier.

Comment: I deleted that question. I removed the mention of that no to confuse people.

Comment: If there were a diagram of the configuration you intend, I might have spent time on this problem.

Comment: I don't care about downvotes. And i didn't get any answer. My subproblem was asking how to get a point's coordinates from a right triangle so I could relate the new point D I am looking for to the point I know how to solve for (r,s). This problem 1 example is very common in robotics e.g. as state here: https://robotacademy.net.au/masterclass/inverse-kinematics-and-robot-motion/?lesson=289 I am sorry if this question seemed like I am playing games but I just seek help and am not extremely familiar with the etiquette over here.

Comment: Then you should have improved **that post**, not delete it and ask it again!

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry about that.

Comment: Please, just don't repeat the same in the future.

Comment: @ruffy  once you earn a bit more in the way of reputation, you'll be able to insert images into your post, like I did above.

Comment: @amWhy Yes that looks much better, thank you for editing!

Comment: @ruffy Solve the problem for fixed point $D$ and lengths $\,a_2, \sqrt{a_3^2+d^2}\,$, then add $\,\arctan(d / a_3)\,$ to the second angle.

Comment: @dxiv Could you specify this a bit more and or formulate as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right triangle $\triangle CBD$ has fixed-size legs of lengths $a_3$ and $d$ respectively, so its hypotenuse will have fixed length $\sqrt{a_3^2+d^2}$ by Pythagoras' theorem.

Given the fixed point $D$ and the known distances $a_2$ and $\sqrt{a_3^2+d^2}\,$, the angles $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3^{\,'}$ can be determined as shown in the posted solution to the first problem, where $\theta_3^{\,'}$ is the angle between $BD$ and the dashed line marked with an arrow.

The last step is to note that $\theta_3 - \theta_3^{\,'} = \angle CBD=\arctan(d / a_3)\,$, so $\theta_3 = \theta_3^{\,'} + \arctan(d / a_3)\,$.

Comment: Thank you so far! I can get out Theta_3 just fine, but struggle with theta_2. The way I did it: If the point D = (xd, yd) is first define: l = sqrt(a3^2 + d^2) and redefine the variable that was in my original post defined as d, but I now call b = (xd^2 + yd^2 - l^2 - a2^2)/(2*a2*l). Then theta_3 = atan2(b, +-sqrt(1-b^2) + atan2(d/a3).  But what is theta_2? I thought analog to problem 1 it should be:  atan2(xd, yd) - atan2(a2+l*cos(theta_3), l*sin(theta_3)) but that does not come out right. How do I do theta_2?

Comment: Looking more into this, I can draw up some triangles and can get the angle between a line AC and a2, but I always end up with calculations that require the point C. Because when I have angle alpha between AC and a2, I could get the angle between the x-axis and AC to from which I would only subtract angle alpha to get theta_3 but this would require knowing point C which I don't know.

Comment: @ruffy Once you solved the first case, all you have to do is substitute $\,(r,s) \mapsto (x_d,y_d)\,$ and $\,(a_2,a_3) \mapsto (a_2,\sqrt{a_3^2+d^2})\,$.

Comment: Let me work through this and draw up a few images for you trying to show you why I think this is not possible. I can do this tomorrow.